# Trying to round the age in an aggregate function in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb

```
db.patients.aggregate([ 
{$unwind: "$patient"}, 
{$project: 
{ "patient.city": 1, 
"patient.age": 1, 
}}, 
{$group: {_id: "$patient.city", avgAge: {$avg: "$patient.age"}}}, 
])


My Results:

/* 1 */
{
"_id" : "Port Moody",
"avgAge" : 56.5987261146497
}

/* 2 */
{
"_id" : "North Vancouver",
"avgAge" : 59.8141592920354
}
```

etc.

I want to Round the numbers in the results to get the Average Age for each city. For example 57 in Port Moody, 60 in North Vancouver, etc. Can anyone help me out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

simply add a $project in your pipeline so you're query become this :

```
db.patients.aggregate([
   {
      $unwind:"$patient"
   },
   {
      $group:{
         _id:"$patient.city",
         avgAge:{
            $avg:"$patient.age"
         }
      }
   },
   {
      $project:{
         _id: 1,
         avgAge:{
            $subtract:[
               "$avgAge",
               {
                  $mod:[
                     "$avgAge",
                     1
                  ]
               }
            ]
         }
      }
   }
])
```